# Finding the max number of characters in a CSV file column

Tags: macos, csv, command-line

I am a Mac Newbie and need to import csv files into a mssql database.  Large csv files. I am using the import wizard for the actual import but I am having a hard time determining the longest string for each column.

I have found the following command line which will show the values in the selected column:

```
cut -d, -f<column number> <path to csv file name>
```

Now I would like to output the longest length of that column.  Props to anyone who could help me return the length for all columns.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This simplistic approach is not going to help with real CSV files that have newlines and separators (`,`) in (quoted) cell content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as @jpw sugested

my answer:

why not use awk ?

I don't have a mac to test, but length() is a pretty standard function in awk, so this should work.

awk file:

```
 { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
    l=length($i) ;
    if ( l > linesize[i] ) linesize[i]=l ;
  }
}
END {
    for (l in linesize) printf "Columen%d: %d\n",l,linesize[l] ;
}
```

then run

```
mybox$ awk -F, -f test.awk  a.txt
Columen4: 4
Columen5: 3
Columen1: 6
Columen2: 7
Columen3: 4
```

To get columns sorted :

```
BEGIN{ maxi=-1 ; }
 { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
    l=length($i) ;
    if ( l > linesize[i] ) linesize[i]=l ;
        if ( i > maxi ) maxi = i ;
   }
  }
END {
    for (i=1;i<=maxi;i++) printf "Columen%d: %d\n",i,linesize[i] ;
}
```

gives:

```
mybox$ awk -F, -f test.awk a.txt
Columen1: 6
Columen2: 7
Columen3: 4
Columen4: 4
Columen5: 3
```

Comment: Oh this is brilliant. I was messing around with `readline`, but this is much, much faster.

Answer (score 2):

The first part of your question is answered in the post flagged as duplicate, but to apply that for all columns this bash one-line script will give you the max length for all columns (based on the first line of the file):

```
for((i=1;i< `head -1 test.csv|awk '{print NF}' FS=,`+1 ;i++)); do echo  | xargs echo -n "Column$i: " && cut -d, -f $i test.csv |wc -L  ; done
```

To explain how it works, the for loop starts from 1 and uses `awk` to determine the number of columns, and then does the `cut -d, -f <column number>` with pipe (|) through `wc -L` to return max length.

The output from my sample file with five columns:

```
Column1: 6
Column2: 7
Column3: 4
Column4: 4
Column5: 3
```

You could even put it in a shell-script that takes the filename of the csv file as argument:

```
#!/bin/bash

for((i=1;i< `head -1 $1|awk '{print NF}' FS=,`+1 ;i++));
do echo  | xargs echo -n "Column$i: "
&& cut -d, -f $i $1 |wc -L  ; done
```

Save this as `something.sh`, then do `chmod + x something.sh` and execute it with `./something.sh your_csv_file.csv`

Comment: Thank you for your kind assistance but when I run this through the mac terminal I receive the following error for each column in the table:wc: illegal option -- L
usage: wc [-clmw] [file ...].  i tried running the code again using all the parameters listed in the error message  but get strange rules when I run them.  151822
  151822
  151822 and there are nowhere near that many characters in the string

Comment: @MichaelBW Oh, I tried it on Linux, it seems the Mac version of wc doesn't support -L. Let me look into that.

Comment: @MichaelBW I can't find a quick solution right now (it's the middle of the night where I am), but I'll look into it tomorrow as I'm sure it's possible to fix.

Comment: I appreciate your time and effort.  Thanks

Comment: Look at the answer provided by @Archemar, it should work and he should get credit for providing the accepted answer (I asked the question on the SE Unix&Linux site).

Comment: @MichaelBW You can see the question I asked on the other site here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153697/determine-maximum-column-length-for-every-column-in-csv-file There's a few answers there that might be interesting.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the assistance.  As a newbie to the CLI I am amazed by all of it's capabilities

Comment: @MichaelBW Happy to help and I share your amazement :)